# Chebyshev's theorem

Tags: standard-deviation

OK, so here's the question (not *my* homework -  which is line segments -_-)

> According to Chebyshev's theorem, how
>   many standard deviations from the mean
>   would make up the central 60% of
>   scores for this class? [What are the
>   corresponding grades? Answer the same
>   questions for central 80%. Do these
>   values capture more than the desired
>   amount? Does this agree with
>   Chebyshev's theorem?]

(The stuff in brackets doesn't need to be answered. I included it there just in case.)

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So $P(|X-\mu| \geq k \sigma) \leq \frac{1}{k^2}$. The central $60 \%$ is $1-P(|X-\mu| \leq k \sigma) = 0.4$.

Answer (score 2):

This is the one that says the probability of being outside $k$ standard deviations is less than $\frac{1}{k^2}$.  So $1-0.6=\frac{1}{k^2}$.  Solve for $k$.  Then change .6 to .8.

Answer (score 0):

Starting with $$0.6=1-1/k^2,$$ then $$1/k^s=1-0.6,$$   then   $$1/k^2=0.4,$$  then $$1=0.4k^2,$$    then   $$1/0.4=k^2,$$ then      $$2.5=k^2,$$     then you square root each side and you will find $k$.

Comment: Welcome to MSE! It helps readability to format questions/answers using MathJax (See FAQ). Regards